# How to watch the answers of a user?

Tags: support

I have been asked how you can subscribe to a user's answer (mine actually) or follow them?  Is there an RSS feed or similar where developers can subscribe to my answers?

There are people I would like to subscribe to/follow as well.

Comment: No idea what it actually tells you but on the bottom right of your profile is a ["user feed"](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/57695) link

Comment: @OGHaza It was off the bottom of my screen. ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [user RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/57695) of all posts.  It's not limited to just answers.

There's a link to the feed at the bottom of every user's profile.